# What is the concrete class that has implemented the hasMoreElements() that belongs to the Enumeration Interface?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

class FileEnumerator implements Enumeration<InputStream> {

    private Enumeration<String> files;

    public FileEnumerator(Vector<String> files) {
        this.files = files.elements();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return this.files.hasMoreElements(); //  ------- >>>> This Method ??
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream nextElement() {
        try {
            return new FileInputStream(this.files.nextElement().toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Vector<String> files = new Vector<>();
        files.add("file1.txt");
        files.add("file2.txt");
        files.add("file3.txt");
        SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(
                new FileEnumerator(files));
        int c;
        while ((c = sequenceInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
        sequenceInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I am totally confused .. I don't know where the hasMoreElement() method  in Enumeration interface has been implemented to return true or false .. since in this program didn't include it's only concrete class which is StringTTokenizer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

Also there is not such a method stand alone in Vector class ..

I just don't get it ...

Comment: If you look carefully, instance of a concrete implementation of Enumeration is retrieved at line: 
`this.files = files.elements();`
the elements() method of Vector return Enumeration which has the "hasMoreElements" method.

Comment: There isn't *one.* There is one per collection class that you can enumerate.

Comment: @MikeNQ Thanks sirrrr ... I am not confused any more ... appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the overridden method in `Vector` class.

```
public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return count < elementCount;
}
```

You called `files.elements();` The method that I mentioned above, is in this `file.elements()` method.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's my pleasure. Accept my answer and vote up.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're questioning this,

```
@Override
public boolean hasMoreElements() {
    return this.files.hasMoreElements(); //  ------- >>>> This Method ??
}
```

Seems like an example of the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) on the [`Vector#elements()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elements%28%29) [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) (and that is the concrete implementation you are looking for).